# remove extra widget/window in Qt

Tags: qt

probably a simple question: I just created a new project in Qt creator and I set it to use QWidget when I created it, now how do I get rid of the window that it automatically creates when I run it? I also created my own QWidget window which I want to be the only window.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QtGui>

Widget::Widget()

{
    QWidget* window = new QWidget;
    addBtn = new QPushButton("Add Module");
    text = new QTextEdit();
    text->setReadOnly(true);
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(addBtn,5);
    layout->addWidget(text);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Just don't create it? Widget is already a widget, why do you create another QWidget in the constructor if you don't want one?

Comment: because I don't know how to add the layout to the already created one that's why I created my own

Comment: Then you should spend a bit more time studying the examples on qt-project.org (and probably with a good C++ book), because it looks like you're missing some fundamentals here. Which will make for a miserable experience and frustration trying to code. But hint: what do you think replacing the before-last line in your constructor with just `setLayout(layout);` would mean? What would it call assuming it compiled?

Answer (score 0):

change it like this

```
Widget::Widget()

{        
    addBtn = new QPushButton("Add Module");
    text = new QTextEdit();
    text->setReadOnly(true);
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(addBtn,5);
    layout->addWidget(text);
    this->setLayout(layout);
}
```

and try to have some time on look and try some of Qt Example (you can find it in Qt Creator)

and there is about [100 short video](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) to learn quickly basic stuff on Qt

Qt is fun, enjoy it.